# Animate textblock when the value changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I want to have an animation similar to this one (the score board, when the 2 becomes a 4) : [gif example](https://giphy.com/gifs/26BRtwCxNCLVvN4g8)

Using this article : https://michaelscherf.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/how-to-trigger-an-animation-when-textblocks-text-is-changed-during-a-databinding/, I have been able to modify the opacity of my textblock when the text changes.

But I don't see at all how I can make the same translation effect ?

My textblock will also containing only numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this with the concept being of just giving the illusion of the ticker. Remove the `Framework.Loaded` trigger when you've hooked up your data binding. The Red/Green Text is to illustrate the illusion you're going for. Wherein the Green would retain the original value via a one-time, and the Red would be the new value. Also remember to add the NotifyTargetUpdated binding thingy from your example link to your binding base. Of course you'll likely need to tweak some values to get exactly what you're after.

Also don't forget to remove the `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` from the Storyboard as it's also just there for the sake of the this initial example.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="flipItGood" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" 
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="A">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" 
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="B">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="20"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <!-- THIS IS HERE ONLY FOR AN IMMEDIATE EXAMPLE
                 DITCH THIS TRIGGER FOR THE TARGET.UPDATED ONE WHEN ACTUALLY USING -->
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource flipItGood}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>

        <TextBlock x:Name="A" 
                   Text="BIND ME" 
                   Foreground="Red" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"
                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="-20"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>

            <TextBlock.Triggers>

                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource flipItGood}"/>
                </EventTrigger>

            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="B" 
                           Text="BIND ME" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"
                           Foreground="Green" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>

    </Grid>
```

Which results in (sorry for the crappy gif);

[image]

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot, I've tried to test your example but I didn't manage to make it work (I don't really use a lot of animations in WPF). I think I didn't understand how it should work (do I need to bind the Text value to the textblock A and textblock B ? (I've edited my first post with my whole code) Thank you :)

Comment: You have to set the `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` property to true in the `Binding`. i.e. `Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"`

Comment: Ah glad to know old questions are still helping, yea the poc didn't include that part and was just static, since it runs off binding.targetupdated that's good looking out 