# WPF Animation (slide in and slide out) when selected item changed

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I have a grid with list box in one column and the selected item of the list box in the other column. I would like to add animation when the selected tool is changed. And require the animation to be slide out the previous selected item and slide in the current selected item. Is that possible just using simple XAML?

For now, I am just able to add animation to slide from left, that too out of margin.

Is it possible to establish animation like [this link](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/left-and-right-slide-animations-on-android-activity-or-view) (i.e) the previously selected item must slide out and disappear, at the same time the currently selected item must slide in and occupy the full space?

The following is my code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SubtoolSection_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {

            var sb = (Storyboard)FindResource("FlowRight");
            sb.Begin();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{

    public ObservableCollection<ItemClass> ListSource { get; set; }

    public ItemClass SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        ListSource = new ObservableCollection<ItemClass>();
        ListSource.Add(new ItemClass() { ItemName = "Item1", Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SkyBlue) });
        ListSource.Add(new ItemClass() { ItemName = "Item2", Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Silver) });
        ListSource.Add(new ItemClass() { ItemName = "Item3", Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SlateBlue) });
        ListSource.Add(new ItemClass() { ItemName = "Item4", Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SpringGreen) });
        SelectedItem = ListSource[0];
    }
}

public class ItemClass
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Background { get; set; }

}
```

My XAML code,

```
<Window x:Class="SlideSelectedToolAnimation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SlideSelectedToolAnimation"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="FlowRight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="SubtoolSection">
        <ThicknessAnimation From ="-200,0,0,0" To="0 , 0 , 0, 0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="myList" ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ListBox>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="{Binding SelectedItem.Background}"  x:Name="SubtoolSection"  >
        <TextBlock TargetUpdated="SubtoolSection_TargetUpdated" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.ItemName, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If it were me I would fake it with the illusion of swapping two things. So for example, on Selection changed fired off the animation to pull the Border out (I'd use Transform/TranslateX though instead of Margin) then after confirmation the bound text has changed to the new selecteditem name then fire off a second animation to bring it back. Or short version, Slide Out -> Update Binding -> Slide Back In. Easy peasy.

Comment: Or, you could fake it like I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713902/animate-textblock-when-the-value-changes).