# WinUI 3 Desktop MVVM; Animate TextBlock on property change?

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, mvvm, winui-3

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to animate a TextBlock when it's property updates. New to WinUI3/XAML but I've found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-apply-animations-to-text which gives a lot of examples that work, but they all use TextBlock.Loaded. I've tried changing it to TargetUpdated, SourceUpdated, FrameWork.x, Binding.x etc, all crash so I'm not sure what to put in there. Lot's of example on the net, but ones I can find seem to be either WPF or UWP which still crash.

My code which is pretty much same as MS's examples sans binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Viewmodel.UpdatedText, Mode=OneWay}">
  <TextBlock.Foreground>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MySolidColorBrush" Color="Maroon" />
  </TextBlock.Foreground>

  <TextBlock.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" From="DarkOrange" To="SteelBlue" Duration="0:0:1" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Which does work, when it loads, but I would like to animate it when the text is updated.

One of the examples I found was [Animate textblock when the value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713902/animate-textblock-when-the-value-changes), but it uses .Loaded as well. In the comments it mentions "You have to set the NotifyOnTargetUpdated property to true in the Binding", but NotifyOnTargetUpdated doesn't seem to exist (in WinUI?).

Answer is probably simple but I'm a bit lost on this. I'm also using MVVM pattern so avoiding code behind, but it seems like something this simple shouldn't need it looking at Microsoft's examples? Though If I'm please feel free to correct me. Thanks!

Comment: Triggers should not be used with WinUI3 which is quite different from WPF (and also UWP), see this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.eventtrigger?view=winui-3.0#remarks In your code, `Loaded` is the only trigger supported by WinUI3. Solution is not general and depends on what you really want to do (transition, storyboard, etc): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/motion/xaml-animation There are also good chances that you can't do everything in pure XAML PS: TextBlock's text is not supposed to change often vs TextBox so it has not an event.

Comment: Oh that's a shame, new to XAML so it's hard to get a grasp as there's seemingly so many different versions. Guess I'll have to figure it out in code behind then, which isn't too big of a deal but wanted to try and avoid it. I have the TextBlock bound to a property (using INotify and all that) which updates its text when new data comes in. I thought it'd be simple to have it 'blink' a color when it's updated. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah ... there have been great disturbances in the XAML world these last years. Make sure you're looking at the proper documentation (eg: WinUI3 and not WPF, not Silverlight, not Windows 8, not UWP...)

Comment: Why would you "avoiding code behind"? Implementing animations in the code-behind of the view is perfectly fine as far as both MVVM and best practice is concerned. If you think about it, where else should you implement them? In the view model? No. In the XAML markup? Probably not.

Comment: MVVM/XAML is totally new to me (I've always used winforms), so I've been trying to follow this book on how to do things and it avoids code behind as much as it can so far. So I was under the impression that code behind was 'bad'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to "avoid code-behind" in cases like this is usually a mistake. View-related logic should be implemented in the view (or control) using a programming language. This does *not* break the MVVM pattern in any way as the pattern is not about trying to eliminate code from the views in the first place.

Using a *markup* language such as XAML to implement farily advanced UI logic is generally an antipattern and in the case of UWP and WinUI 3, it's not even possible to use triggers to accomplish what you want.

To quote the [ReactiveUI docs](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-models/), "C# is a much more expressive, more concise language than XAML, and while it may be possible for you to create an entire complex view without writing any code, the result will be an unmaintainable, difficult to read mess."

My suggestion would be to implement the animation programmtically, either directly in the code-behind of the view or as part of an attached behaviour or custom control.

Comment: Yeah it looks like I'll have to do that. It would make things easier than having to deal with XAML. I'll read the docs, thanks!

Comment: Great suggestion. Where did you find documentation on WinUI animation. I can't find anything. I just want to animate the foreground color of a textblock when the value changes.

Comment: I didn't find/look for any WinUI specific documentation in this context, did I?